# Simple cellular automata in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, cellular-automata

I'm currently trying to implement something like a simple cellular automata in Unity3D. The main idea is a cube, that infinitely clones itself if there are no other obstacles around it.

Here is a basic schematics of it:

[image: Here is a basic schematics of it.]

I started with this code:

```
public class Cube : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform prefab;
    void Start()
    {
        Vector3 CurrentObjPos = transform.position;
        Debug.Log("Current Position is:" + CurrentObjPos);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
                {

                    Instantiate(prefab, CurrentObjPos + new Vector3(i, j, k), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

Currently it makes 2x2 cube at position of an original cube. But I am not sure how to make it expand infinitely and detect collision.

Comment: Infinitely sounds like a bad idea. You would run out of memory eventually. There should be some arbitrary safety limit where you stop beforehand.

Comment: You can use recursion, or just have each cube in its start function spawn its immediate neighbors, which spawn its immediate neighbors in their cube start function -- but as mentioned, this may soon come to a (literal) stack overflow.

Comment: @PhilippLenssen Yeah, I fully understand that stack overflow may occur, so I will limit it by obstacles. But If we are talking about spawning immediate neighbors, how do I detect already occupied cells and avoid overlapping? I just don't have much experience with Unity.

Comment: You could have all cubes snap to a defined grid (say at steps of 1m in each direction), then check if any other cube is there as per transform.position. Or, perhaps easier, you let each new cube shoot off a [detection ray](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) in all four directions, and only spawn to that direction if empty. If it's a flat grid board, you could also express that structure as a global x,y bool array and manage occupied list positions in that central place.

Comment: Yeah, a global grid would be better and also easier to work with. It also comes with a built-in limitation for the size. I would not just rely on a collision check against obstacles for the fear of some unforeseen physics bug that would then lead to an overflow for the player.

Comment: @PhilippLenssen So, I've done it, but now there are a problem, that it becomes really laggy, when at least 16x16 cubes (which I limited by walls, so it's not infinitely expanding) constantly checks for it's neighbors in still condition, since I want to make it adaptive depending on moving obstacles. Any way to optimize it somehow? Or Unity cubes isn't the best idea? Because for example if I change cube scale from 1x1x1 to 2x2x2 it becomes twice laggier and FPS drops even more. And if I use 3D modelled cube-like shapes, it becomes a complete nightmare.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Unity, but what you describe (i.e. trying to make each cube an autonomous object) is almost certainly a bad idea. What you probably want to do is have a single CellularAutomaton object that stores the state of all cells on the lattice (e.g. as a three-dimensional array of booleans, or as a set of (x,y,z) coordinate tuples), updates it according to the CA evolution rule at suitable time intervals, and then creates and positions child objects at the locations where the array says there should be one.

Comment: … Ideally your CA update step shouldn't be doing _any_ raycasts or collision checks or any other similar interactions, although you may need some if, as you say, you want the CA to interact with moving obstacles.

Comment: @GeneralBeta You want the existing cubes to move based on their surrounding? In that case, try setting up a larger box collider as "is trigger" and use OnTriggerEnter on it.